# Uploading large files to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, uploadify

I've manage to get the following script to work with smaller files. But when I try to upload files around 10MB or more, it says that it is completed but the file does not show up in my S3 bucket.

Any ideas why it will upload smaller files and not file 10MB or greater?

```
<?php
//System path for our website folder
define('DOCROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
//URL for our website
define('WEBROOT', htmlentities(
    substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, strcspn($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "\n\r")),
    ENT_QUOTES
));

//Which bucket are we placing our files into
$bucket = 'bucket.mysite.com';
// This will place uploads into the '20100920-234138' folder in the $bucket bucket
$folder = date('Ymd-His').'/'; //Include trailing /

//Include required S3 functions
require_once DOCROOT."includes/s3.php";

//Generate policy and signature
list($policy, $signature) = S3::get_policy_and_signature(array(
    'bucket'        => $bucket,
    'folder'        => $folder,
    ));
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#file_upload").uploadify({
            'uploader'      : '<?= WEBROOT ?>files/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'buttonText'        : 'Browse',
            'cancelImg'     : '<?= WEBROOT ?>files/uploadify/cancel.png',
            'script'        : 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/<?= $bucket ?>',
            'scriptAccess'      : 'always',
            'method'        : 'post',
            'scriptData'        : {
                "AWSAccessKeyId"        : "<?= S3::$AWS_ACCESS_KEY ?>",
                "key"               : "${filename}",
                "acl"               : "authenticated-read",
                "policy"            : "<?= $policy ?>",
                "signature"         : "<?= $signature ?>",
                "success_action_status"     : "201",
                "key"               : encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent("<?= $folder ?>${filename}")),
                "fileext"           : encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent("")),
                "Filename"          : encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(""))
            },
            'fileExt'       : '*.*',
            'fileDataName'      : 'file',
            'simUploadLimit'    : 2,
            'multi'         : true,
            'auto'          : true,
            'onError'       : function(errorObj, q, f, err) { console.log(err); },
            'onComplete'        : function(event, ID, file, response, data) { console.log(file); }
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

```
 <?php
    class S3 {
        public static $AWS_ACCESS_KEY       = '< Your access key >';
        public static $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY    = '< Your secrete key >';


    /*
     * Purpose:
     *      Actionscript encodes '+' characters in the signature incorrectly - it makes
     *      them a space instead of %2B the way PHP does. This causes uploadify to error
     *      out on upload. This function recursively generates a new policy and signature
     *      until a signature without a + character is created.
     * Accepts: array $data
     * Returns: policy and signature
     */
    public static function get_policy_and_signature( array $data )
    {
        $policy = self::get_policy_doc( $data );
        $signature = self::get_signature( $policy );

        if ( strpos($signature, '+') !== FALSE )
        {
            $data['timestamp'] = intval(@$data['timestamp']) + 1;
            return self::get_policy_and_signature( $data );
        }

        return array($policy, $signature);
    }

    public static function get_policy_doc(array $data)
    {
        return base64_encode(
            '{'.
                '"expiration": "'.gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', time()+60*60*24+intval(@$data['timestamp'])).'",'.
                '"conditions": '.
                '['.
                    '{"bucket": "'.$data['bucket'].'"},'.
                    '["starts-with", "$key", ""],'.
                    '{"acl": "authenticated-read"},'.
                    //'{"success_action_redirect": "'.$SWFSuccess_Redirect.'"},'.
                    '{"success_action_status": "201"},'.
                    '["starts-with","$key","'.str_replace('/', '\/', $data['folder'] ).'"],'.
                    '["starts-with","$Filename",""],'.
                    '["starts-with","$folder",""],'.
                    '["starts-with","$fileext",""],'.
                    '["content-length-range",0,5242880]'.
                ']'.
            '}'
        );
    }

    public static function get_signature( $policy_doc ) {
        return base64_encode(hash_hmac(
            'sha1', $policy_doc, self::$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, true
        ));
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved issue was with this line

```
'["content-length-range",0,5242880]'
```

I commented it out and it works as it should. with no limits in size.